# How to update old version of the app with the newest version (Internal testing)?

Tags: google-play, google-play-internal-testing

I uploaded my  Android application to internal testing. The app can be downloaded successfully,  but when I uploaded a new version of the app, the old version is not updated by the new version on the tester's device. What may be the possible reason for that issue?
Thanks

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem. Even full reinstall gets internal testers the old version.